# how to hide K2 intro image in content page?

Tags: joomla3.0, joomla-k2

I am using Joomla 3.x and K2 extension. I'd like to hide the attached image of the item in intro text, and show another image instead in the content page (full page). (The image that shown in the main page replaced by another image in the article/content page). How can I do that?

Comment: I don't get the idea, there's no attached image in the introtext (in K2).

Answer (score 0):

In K2, you can associate an image with an item by uploading it to the Image tag for that item. You can also add images within the content of the item as well. To accomplish what you are trying to do it would probably be easiest to do this -

1. Configure the category view to display the image from the image tab
2. Configure the detail view to NOT display the image from the image tab
3. Use a template override for the category item view that strips out any images in the intro text

This way you will have the image tab image display in the category and the content image shown on the detail page.

Answer (score 0):

Under the category, go to "Item view options" (on the right), and select "hide" for "image".

Make sure if your category inherits from another one, you make this change in the top category